# How to save web scraped data to a new excel column with vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a sheet that I collect the webpage data with columns from A:F

I want to put the old data in column E, from T column and onwards for each time I run the VBA module

I did for now something like

```
wks.Cells(i, "T").Value = wks.Cells(i, "E").Value
```

How can I make it to advace each time?

The full code is the following

```
For i = 2 To 17

LRandomNumber = Int((15 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value

ie.Navigate mylink



While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next

    wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38

    Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price-container .final-price")

    myprice = CCur(price.innerText)


    checkprice = myprice * 1.24


    'FORMAT PRICE
    If wks.Cells(i, "E").Value < checkprice Then wks.Cells(i, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Else wks.Cells(i, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = myprice * 1.24

    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".inner-box-one .availability")
    wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText

    Set product_name = ie.Document.querySelector(".title-container h1.title")
    wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = product_name.innerText

    If Timer - t > LRandomNumber Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
If price Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Next i
```

We need to put

'COPY PRICE
 Call TransferDataFromColumnE(wks)

Outside the For loop

Comment: you want to copy the data from column E to column T without keep the data in column E?

Comment: The data in column E will be changed nevertheless next time I run the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think you could determine the last column containing data by:

```
Dim lastColumn as long
lastColumn = wks.cells(1, wks.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
lastColumn = application.max(lastColumn + 1, wks.columns("T").column)
' The Application.Max is meant to guarantee you either write to column T or any column to the right of it.
' +1 is so that we don't overwrite the last column, but instead write to the column after it.
```

Then you could continue with your code (although it might be better/quicker to assign the entire range/column in one go rather than each cell/row individually).

```
wks.Cells(i, lastColumn).Value = wks.Cells(i, "E").Value
```

---

**Edit:** Here's a tested example. Say I have some data in column E starting on row 2 on a sheet called `"Sheet2"`.

[image: Before code runs]

I can use the code below to copy-paste it to the last column (where the last column is either column `T` or the first empty column to the right of it).

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferDataFromColumnE()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = wks.Cells(2, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastColumn = Application.Max(lastColumn + 1, wks.Columns("T").Column)

    With wks.Range("E2:E24") ' This is the range I need to copy in my case
        Dim columnOffset As Long
        columnOffset = lastColumn - .Columns(1).Column

        .Copy
        .Offset(0, columnOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

And this is what I get after I've run the code three times -- which I think is what you want.

[image: After code runs]

Comment: It overwrites the T column with the new values is not advancing to the next column to write new values

Comment: @Nikos, is there data in cell `T1`? The codes relies on data being written to row 1 of whatever column is being written to.

Comment: After the first run T2 had values so the next data should be written on U2 based on the above?

Comment: @Nikos, since the values are being written to cell `T2`, the quickest fix might be just to change this line `lastColumn = wks.cells(1, wks.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column` to `lastColumn = wks.cells(2, wks.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column` (note how the `1` becomes `2`).

Comment: I added a j counter lastColumn = wks.cells(  j, wks.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column  j=j+1 but only writes on the first U2 and not the rest below

Comment: @Nikos, I don't understand what you mean. Does my edit help explain my answer? Otherwise, I think you'll need to post your code and a screenshot of your sheet/data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185846/discussion-between-nikos-and-chillin).